# fullCalendar js is adding events start date one day early and ending event date one day early

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

We have an events calendar page that pulls data from a web service. We are using fullCalendar js to load this data into the calendar. The problem we are facing is, the start and end dates are all one day early when displayed in  month view.
[month view screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9zmO.png) The start and end dates are correct when displayed in week view. [week view screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adCrC.png). Here is a screen shot of the data in the console, [data screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Cqdd.png)

```
  jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        header: {
            left: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'prev,next'
        },
        defaultView: 'month',
        events: {
            url: eventsSource
        },
        contentHeight: "auto",
        ignoreTimezone: true,
        displayEventEnd: {
            month: false,
            basicWeek: false,
            "default": false
        },
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
            if(event.event_type !== ""){
                var evtType = event.event_type;
                if(evtType == '075'){
                    evtType = 'WEBINAR';
                }
                element.addClass(evtType);
            }
        },
        eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            if (calEvent.externalURL.length<1){
                window.location.href = "/events/event-details?EventID=" + calEvent.id;
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = calEvent.externalURL;
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is a sample of the raw json:

```
[
{

    "id": "82712",
    "title": "86th UFI Global Congress - Bangkok, Thailand",
    "alt_title": "86th UFI Global Congress - Bangkok, Thailand",
    "start_date_formatted": "11/6/2019",
    "end_date_formatted": "11/9/2019",
    "start_date_week": "Wed",
    "end_date_week": "Sat",
    "start_date_week_formatted": "Wednesday",
    "end_date_week_formatted": "Saturday",
    "start_day": "6",
    "end_day": "9",
    "start_month_year": "Nov 2019",
    "end_month_year": "Nov 2019",
    "start": "2019-11-06T08:00:00",
    "end": "2019-11-09T17:00:00",
    "startTime": "8:00 AM",
    "endTime": "5:00 PM",
    "event_type": "CNF",
    "event_class": "MKTG",
    "eventSummary": "",
    "eventVenue": "",
    "externalURL": "",
    "allDay": "False"

}
]
```

Comment: The first thing to note is that end dates are **exclusive**. See the note on the "end" property in  https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-object . So if you have an event which ends at midnight on Friday (which, if you haven't specified a time for that event, is what it is treated as), then the event will not be shown on Friday, because it doesn't actually occupy any of Friday's time. It effectively ends a millisecond before Friday begins. N.B. I haven't seen your actual data but I've seen this issue often enough to guess what is happening.

Comment: However if you're saying the **start** dates are also a day early, that is a bit odd. Again you haven't shown the actual event data or any screenshots of the issue, so it's a bit harder to figure this one out. But maybe there's a timezone issue or something. That or the server isn't producing the data you think it is.

Comment: @ADyson, I edited my question with screen shots of the month view and week view and also added a shot of the logged data from chrome dev tools

Comment: It would be much more helpful to have a text block containing the raw JSON returned from the server to be honest. Then I can actually test it. Thanks

Comment: @ADyson, ok I added raw JSON. Let me know if this helps. Thanks!

Comment: Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/8x2kvwnf/ - I cannot reproduce your issue using your code and data. From your screenshots it looks like you've changed the CSS quite significantly. I can only guess that you may have done something which has accidentally caused this problem. Try removing your CSS customisations and see if you still have a problem.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for taking the time to look at this. The moment.js file that we referenced was the culprit. Grabbed the latest and everything is working. Thanks again!